# Как распаралелить pyfpgrowth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, распараллеливание

Кто знает как распараллелить метод ассоциативных правил и можно ли это сделать?

```
pyfpgrowth.generate_association_rule()
```

В библиотеке `pandarallel` не нашла как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Я когда-то столкнулся с проблемой очень медленной обработки при поиске ассоциативных правил. Перебробовал несколько питоновских модулей - все они либо ужасно медленно работали либо работали нестабильно.

В итоге пришел к решению, которое вызывает из Python [бинарный файл, написанный на `C`](http://www.borgelt.net/fpgrowth.html).

Время работы сократилось с нескольких часов до полутора десятка секунд.

Comment: можно попросить сбросить ссылку, где пример использование данного пакета.